# Change in behavior in Tomcat when redirecting to an empty string

Tags: jsp, tomcat, redirect

The code below generates a different response when running under different releases of Tomcat.

```
response.sendRedirect("");
```

Under Tomcat 7.0.47, Location header in the respons is set to

```
http://value-of-Host-header-in-the-request/
```

Under Tomcat 7.0.69, Location header is set to an empty string.

Is this configurable?  Is the difference in behavior due to different configurable settings int the two Tomcat instances?  Or is it a deliberate change in behavior and requires code change to compensate for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tomcat change the behavior after version v7.0.67/v8.0.30, due to [this bug](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56917).

You can set `useRelativeRedirects="false"` in [Context config](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html) or add system property `org.apache.catalina.STRICT_SERVLET_COMPLIANCE=true`.

Comment: Thanks! I used the first suggested workaround and worked as expected.